# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'mydb.student' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I am try to make simple spring boot api and generate table automaticaly.But whenI call the api  i get an error that tha table not exist ?
my application.properties

````
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123
logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.formate_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
server.error.include-message=always```
````

Answer (score 4):

To generate Tables automatically with spring boot 1. First set your POJO class with the @Entity annotation. 2. Use the bellow Properties and Run the application tables will be created automatically.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Your DB name
spring.datasource.username= username
spring.datasource.password= password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

The four configurations enough to create tables automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You configuration won't generate any tables automatically due to non-emdedded database (MySQL). Therefore you must configure ddl-auto explicitly.

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`
OR
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`

Have a look at [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To generate your tables you need to implement this lines to your application.properties:

```
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/YOURSCHEMA
    spring.datasource.username=YOURUSER
    spring.datasource.password= YOURPASSWORD
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name =com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    spring.jpa.show-sql: true
```

You also need to add some dependencies to run the project like the connector to your db, for example I use MySqlConnector. If you have changed this lines and does not work provide me more info about what you want to do by replying this thread.